# Pyqt form in FreeCAD macro not staying open

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, freecad

Ok. So, I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I'm just stuck. Everytime I try to run this, the window just opens and closes immediately. I just can't seem to figure it out. Please help.

FYI. This is a macro for FreeCAD that creates cylinders. I've made other macros before and they work just fine. I didn't start having trouble until I introduced the PyQt GUI.

```
import FreeCAD, math
from FreeCAD import Base, Draft, Part
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Muffler(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Muffler, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        #Introduce Labels and inputs
        self.t0 = QtGui.QLabel("Cylinder",self)
        self.t01 = QtGui.QLabel(" ",self)
        self.t1 = QtGui.QLabel("Radius of Cylinder (mm)",self)
        self.l1 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.l1.setText("31.75")
        self.t2 = QtGui.QLabel("Length of Cylinder (mm)",self)
        self.l2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.l2.setText("50")

        #Create buttons
        self.createButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Create",self)
        self.cancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel",self)

        #Create window and size it
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.resize(240,180)
        self.setWindowTitle("Cylinder")

        #Design Layout of window
        layout.addWidget(self.t0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.t01, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.t1, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.l1, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.t2, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.l2, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.createButton, 3, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.cancelButton, 3, 1)

        #Set Layout and show it
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

        #Give functionality to the buttons
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.createButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.build)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.cancelButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.close)
    def build(self):
        #some code
    def close(self):
        self.hide()
Muffler()
```

Comment: where is the rest of the code? Where you actually instantiate and show the widget? The error is probably there.

Comment: Since `QtGui.QWidget` is included in the class and identified as `self` in the `init` definition, it can be called with `self.show`. If I add in `sleep(0)` right after I call `self.show`, the window will show but the buttons won't work.

Comment: ok, simple check. Do you have `QtGui.QApplication` in the script anywhere?

Comment: What you see is what I've got. I've used Qt before and it's worked if I introduce a checkbox that relies on a function but it won't work without it. It's a pain.

Comment: Show us the code where you instantiate the class. My guess would be that you don't keep a reference to the newly created object, so it gets destroeyed immediately after it's created.

Comment: Sorry. I added it. It's literally just called at the bottom.

Comment: As i suspected - just calling `Muffler()` will not keep a reference. The object will immediately be destroyed after it's created. Use something like `muffler = Muffler()`.

Comment: @mata keeping a reference won't help much if you don't start the event loop with QApplication.

Comment: @M4rtini - You're right, but obviously the `QApplication` must be instantiated somewhere or he would get an exception trying to instantiate the Widget. So maybe this is just a module used from somewhere else - without further information there isn't really a way to tell wheather the event loop is started or not. Fact is that just calling `Muffler()` will not work. @Code-nerd: you should try to clarify on that.

Comment: I apologize. I did forget to mention that it's a macro for FreeCAD. I'll put that above! I'm a dummy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeCAD is a Qt Application, that means if will already have instantiated a `QApplication` and called it's `exec_()` method. Therfore you don't need to do that in your script, as that can - as you found out - freeze or crash the whole application.

As it seems, macros in FreeCAD are compiled and executed using `exec()`, and therefore their state (global variables) are not preserved once the execution has finished. That means that any QObjects which are owned by PyQt and not by Qt (which basically are all QObjects that have no parent) will be destroyed when they're garbaged collected.

A simple solution to this would be to create a reference outside the macro that will keep the object from being collected. Candidates where to put such a reference could be the `__main__` or any other python module:

```
...
import __main__
__main__.muffler = Muffler()
...
```

Comment: My dear friend, you are a genius! This legitimately fixed it. I owe you. Thanks again! You shall be crowned with the winning answer.

`٩(^‿^)۶`

Answer (score -2):

You are missing some initialisation.

Try this instead of the call to Muffler():

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
my_widget = Muffler()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Don't forget to add at the top:

```
import sys
```

Comment: Since this is a macro for FreeCAD, I can't use the `sys.exit(app.exec_())` since it closes out FreeCAD when it is complete.

Comment: With that said, I removed `sys.exit(app.exec_())` and it now freezes FreeCAD when I run it. The window will still work but all of the functionality of FreeCAD is removed. I end up having to close it.